# F# Flattening Nested Tuples in Computation Expression

Tags: f#, computation-expression

I have a computation expression which I want to return a flattened tuple as the first element and an `int` as the second. I am trying to use method overloading to accomplish this. Right now the compiler is throwing an error saying it cannot find a unique overload. I do not know how to help the compiler figure it out. It appears deterministic to me.

```ml
type IntBuilder () =

    member inline this.Yield (i:int) =
        i

    member inline this.For(source:seq<'a>, body:'a -> seq<'b * int>) =
        source
        |> Seq.collect (fun x -> body x |> Seq.map (fun (idx, i) -> (x, idx), i))

    member inline this.For(source:seq<'a>, body:'a -> int) =
        source |> Seq.map (fun x -> x, body x)

    member inline this.Run(source:seq<('a * ('b * ('c * 'd))) * 'v>) =
        source 
        |> Seq.map (fun ((x, (y, (z, a))), d) -> (x, y, z, a), d)

    member inline this.Run(source:seq<('a * ('b * 'c)) * 'v>) =
        source 
        |> Seq.map (fun ((x, (y, z)), d) -> (x, y, z), d)

    member inline this.Run(source:seq<('a * 'b) * 'v>) =
        source 
        |> Seq.map (fun ((x, y), d) -> (x, y), d)

    member inline this.Run(source:seq<'a * 'v>) =
        source 
        |> Seq.map (fun (x, d) -> x, d)

let intBuilder = IntBuilder ()
let c = 
    intBuilder {
        for i in 1..2 do
            for j in 1..2 do
                for k in 1..2 do
                    for l in 1..2 -> 
                         i + j + k + l
    }

// What I get
c : seq<(int * (int * (int * int))) * int>

// What I want
c : seq<(int * int * int * int) * int>
```

In this case `c` is of type `seq<(int * (int * (int * int))) * int>`. I want the `IntBuilder` computation to return `seq<(int * int * int * int), int>`. How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the only way to get this to work is by wrapping them all in concrete types:

```
type T1<'a> = | T1 of seq<'a * int>
type T2<'a,'b> = | T2 of seq<('a * 'b) * int>
type T3<'a,'b,'c> = | T3 of seq<('a * ('b * 'c)) * int>
type T4<'a,'b,'c,'d> = | T4 of seq<('a * ('b * ('c * 'd))) * int>
type T5<'a,'b,'c,'d,'e> = | T5 of seq<('a * ('b * ('c * ('d * 'e)))) * int>

type IntBuilder () =
    member this.Yield (i:int) =
        i

    member this.For(source:seq<'a>, body:'a -> int) =
        source |> Seq.map (fun x -> x, body x)
        |> T1.T1

     member this.For(source:seq<'a>, body:'a -> T1<'b>) =
        source
        |> Seq.collect (fun x -> 
            body x 
            |> fun (T1.T1 x) -> x
            |> Seq.map (fun (idx, i) -> (x, idx), i))
        |> T2.T2

    member this.For(source:seq<'a>, body:'a -> T2<'b,'c>) =
       source
       |> Seq.collect (fun x -> 
           body x 
           |> fun (T2.T2 x) -> x
           |> Seq.map (fun (idx, i) -> (x, idx), i))
       |> T3.T3

    member this.For(source:seq<'a>, body:'a -> T3<'b,'c,'d>) =
       source
       |> Seq.collect (fun x -> 
           body x 
           |> fun (T3.T3 x) -> x
           |> Seq.map (fun (idx, i) -> (x, idx), i))
       |> T4.T4

    member this.For(source:seq<'a>, body:'a -> T4<'b,'c,'d,'e>) =
        source
        |> Seq.collect (fun x -> 
            body x 
            |> fun (T4.T4 x) -> x
            |> Seq.map (fun (idx, i) -> (x, idx), i))
        |> T5.T5

    member inline this.Run(T1.T1 source) =
        source 
        |> Seq.map (fun (x, d) -> x, d)

    member inline this.Run(T2.T2 source) =
        source 
        |> Seq.map (fun ((x, y), d) -> (x, y), d)

    member inline this.Run(T3.T3 source) =
        source 
        |> Seq.map (fun ((x, (y, z)), d) -> (x, y, z), d)

    member inline this.Run(T4.T4 source) =
        source 
        |> Seq.map (fun ((x, (y, (z, a))), d) -> (x, y, z, a), d)

let intBuilder = IntBuilder ()


let c = 
    intBuilder {
        for i in 1..2 do
            for j in 1..2 do
                for k in 1..2 do
                    for l in 1..2 -> 
                         i + j + k + l
    }
```

FSI output:

```
val c : seq<(int * int * int * int) * int>

> c;;
val it : seq<(int * int * int * int) * int> =
  seq
    [((1, 1, 1, 1), 4); ((1, 1, 1, 2), 5); ((1, 1, 2, 1), 5);
     ((1, 1, 2, 2), 6); ...]
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be solved with in-lining and overload resolution, but in a general sense, (afaik) it's not possible to have a function which can return a type `int * int * ...` based on the arbitrary type of input it's been given. Perhaps someone else can weigh in on this.

We can achieve flattening with run-time type-testing though.

```
let flatten tuple =
    let rec fold (tuple: obj) acc = 
        match tuple with
        | :? int as v -> v::acc
        | :? ITuple as rest ->  
            let next, value = rest.[0], rest.[1] :?> int
            fold next (value::acc)
        | _ -> failwith "Unexpected type"

    fold tuple []

> flatten ((1, 2), 3);;
val it : int list = [1; 2; 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the edited question:

The compiler cannot resolve a correct overload because

```
seq<('a * ('b* ('c * 'd))) * 'v>)
```

is a sub-type of:

```
seq<'u * 'v> where 'u = 'a * ('b* ('c * 'd)))
```

and so on, for the other types. So constrain some of the types into a concrete type. Constraining the innermost tuple type should be sufficient.

For example:

```
member  this.Run(source:seq<('a * ('b* ('c* int))) * 'v>) =
    source 
    |> Seq.map (fun ((x, (y, (z, a))), d) -> (x, y, z, a), d)

member  this.Run(source:seq<('a * ('b* int)) * 'v>) =
    source 
    |> Seq.map (fun ((x, (y, z)), d) -> (x, y, z), d)

member  this.Run(source:seq<('a * int) * 'v>) =
    source 
    |> Seq.map (fun ((x, y), d) -> (x, y), d)

member  this.Run(source:seq<int * 'v>) =
    source 
    |> Seq.map (fun (x, d) -> x, d)
```